# Control react-youtube player with an external button

Tags: reactjs, youtube, embed

i was using the react-youtube package to embed videos , I wanted to play/pause the video when an external  button is clicked , currently i cant think of any way i can implement this-

```js
  const opts = {
    playerVars: {
      disablekb: 1,
      controls: 0,
      autoplay: 1,
      loop: 1,
    },
  };
```

```
  <div>
    <YouTube        
      videoId={vid}
      className="video"
      opts={opts}
      onPause={(e) => {
        !isHost ? e.target.playVideo() : pausePlayback(e);
      }}
      onPlay={(e) => startPlayback()}
    />
    <button type="button" className="end-call-btn" onClick={//want to play/pause the video when this is clicked} />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can control the video play/pause in [react-youtube-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube-player). Can you try using [react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player). This will give you more control over playing the youtube videos.

Comment: Hey ,I figured out how we would go around implementing this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644919/extracting-play-function-of-react-youtube-in-state-to-use-in-button-oncluck-resu?rq=1)